# Is it possible to use explicit member constraints on static fields?

Tags: f#, constraints, type-parameter

Using F#, I had the following (simplified), which works fine:

```
type MyInt =
    struct 
        val Value: int
        new v = { Value = v }
    end
    static member inline name() = "my_int"   // relevant line

let inline getName (tp: ^a): string = (^a: (static member name : unit -> string) ())
```

It seems to me that the statically resolved member signature from the explicit member constraint requires a function. I was wondering if it can also be used with a field instead. I tried a few things:

The following will compile, but won't work and will fail with the error

> error FS0001: The type 'MyInt' does not support the operator 'get_name'

```
type MyInt =
    //...
    static member inline name = "my_int"

let inline getName (tp: ^a): string = (^a: (static member name : string) ())
```

Removing the `()` to prevent it from trying to call the gettor is a syntax error. If I change it to actually implement the gettor, it works (but that's essentially the same as the original code).

```
type MyInt =
    // ...
    static member inline name with get() = "my_int"

let inline getName (tp: ^a): string = (^a: (static member name : string) ())
```

Is there a way to get, using explicit member constraints or similar means, the compiler to find the static field? Or is this simply a limitation of the syntax of constraints?

---

Update:

Surprisingly, it does work with instance fields, or as in this case, struct fields: using `(^a: (member Value: 'b) ())`, which will call the member `Value`.

Comment: Hopefully I'm wrong but AFAIK it doesn't work with static fields. I would be interested as well if someone finds a way to make it work but I think it's simply not supported. If so we should ask in the User Voice to add this feature.

Comment: I'm not able to repro your FS0001 error with the supplied example.

Comment: @kvb, did you use the `static member inline name = "my_int"` approach (fails on my environment)? Or did you use `static member inline name() = "my_int" (works on my environment)? I use F# 4.0 with VS2015, RyuJit (but this fails on compile time), .NET 4.6.

Comment: Both work for me on VS2015 update 3 (works fine both in FSI and when compiled, targeting .NET 4.5.x or 4.6.x).

Comment: @kvb: strange. My code has evolved quite a bit since, and now the repro compiles and runs for me as well (FSI). But when I refactor my original code to use `static member inline name = "xyz"` I now get _error FS1114: The value 'FSI_0012.MyInt.name' was marked inline but was not bound in the optimization environment_, (separate issue on SO). I'm not sure I can re-reproduce it (but I did get the error yesterday...). I could send you the code off-site if you are interested. It is relatively straightforward, but hard to create a min repro example.